# How to cascade delete on multiple columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have a table **user_item** which for recording users and their items relationships like below.

```
create table user_item (
    user_id varchar(255),
    iterm_id varchar(255),
    CONSTRAINT pk_user_item PRIMARY KEY(user_id,iterm_id)
    );


| user_id   | iterm_id  |
|---------  |---------- |
| user123   | item123   |
```

Meanwhile user can group their items into a tag, so we have another table **user_item_tag**

```
| user_id   | iterm_id  | tag_id    |
|---------  |---------- |--------   |
| user123   | item123   | tag123    |
```

Now the question I have is when I delete one item for a user, the relative record should be deleted from table **user_item_tag** simultaneously, I noticed cascade deleting might be helpful for my situation, however when I tried following SQL

```
create table user_item_tag (
    user_id varchar(255),
    item_id varchar(255) references user_item (iterm_id) on delete cascade,
    tag_id varchar(255),
    CONSTRAINT pk_user_item_tag PRIMARY KEY(user_id, item_id, tag_id)
    );
```

It prompts that

> ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "user_item"

Neither could it work even after I add `references user_item (user_id) on delete cascade` to `user_id` column of table **user_item_tag**.

Am I following a wrong way? Or is there any better solution for my issue? really appreciated.

Comment: you have to create one constraint to both columns on user_item since user_id and iterm_id are keys on that table. In order to create a constraint the referenced column must be a key and if it is part of multi key, the constraint must be in all columns for that key.

Comment: Do you mean what @Laurenz Albe wrote below? or an alternative solution? a sample code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Exactly that! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A foreign key has to point to a unique constraint. How else would PostgreSQL know on which individual row in the parent table an entry belongs?

So you'd have to write:

```
CREATE TABLE user_item_tag (
   user_id varchar(255),
   item_id varchar(255),
   tag_id varchar(255),
   CONSTRAINT pk_user_item_tag PRIMARY KEY(user_id, item_id, tag_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (user_id, item_id)
      REFERENCES user_item (user_id, iterm_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

One remarks on the side: `varchar(255)` is long for an indexed key.

Comment: So say many, but I think it is a matter of taste. I just think that 255 characters is quite a lot, it will inflate the index.